# How to insert hard line break in Quarto document

Tags: quarto

I'm working with the Quarto document preparation system to programmatically generate large documents using Python.  That is I am not using the RStudio or similar editor.  All text must be generated as Python strings.

I have a simple table where one cell has several lines worth of content and I figure that I can add line-breaks within the cell.  I understand that simple tables cannot include standard line breaks (`\n`) but I'm wondering if there is a way to insert so-called "hard-line-breaks" in cells.  The [user manual](https://quarto.org/docs/visual-editor/options.html) mentions them but states that only the editor can insert them.  Is it possible to do this using string operations in the markdown source text?

Barring that is there a simple way to break lines within a cell in a table?

Comment: It would be really helpful to provide a reproducible example that is not working for your case so that we can try with that and make that work or suggest workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Quarto tables generated by RStudio visual Markdown editor

There's not much magic involved when it comes to hard line breaks, just lines that end with a `\`.
QMD file created in RStudio with visual mode enabled, a ([Grid](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/tables.html#grid-tables)) table with both regular and hard line breaks looks like this:

```yaml
---
title: "tbl"
format: html
editor: visual
---

+-------+-------------+
| Col1  | Col2        |
+=======+=============+
| press | press\      |
|       | shift+enter |
| enter |             |
+-------+-------------+
|       |             |
+-------+-------------+
```

With all the whitespace and linefeeds next to rendered output:

[image]

While RStudio visual editor starts with simple pipe tables, it switches automatically to grid tables when it encounters a line break or anything else in a cell that's not supported by simple pipe tables.

---

##### Python and grid-style Markdown tables

For generating Markdown grid tables in Python, `tabulate` with `tablefmt="grid"` is quite handy. Or `pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown()` in case of pandas, also built on top of `tabulate`.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

td = [["press\n\nenter","press\\\nshift+enter"],["no\nbackslash","",]]
hdr = ["Col1", "Col2"]
print(tabulate(td,headers=hdr, tablefmt="grid"))
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Col1      | Col2        |
+===========+=============+
| press     | press\      |
|           | shift+enter |
| enter     |             |
+-----------+-------------+
| no        |             |
| backslash |             |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Rendered with Quarto:
[image]

##### Pandoc multiline tables

For whatever reason this is not mentioned in Quarto docs, but Pandoc also supports [multiline_tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-multiline_tables) and rendering it with Quarto & Pandoc that are bundled with RStudio works fine, though for hard line breaks it still needs `\` before a break.
Slighty modified sample from Pandoc documentation:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Centered   Default           Right Left
  Header    Aligned         Aligned Aligned
----------- ------- --------------- -------------------------
   First    row                12.0 Example of\ 
                                    a row that
                                    spans multiple lines.

  Second    row                 5.0 Here's another one. Note
                                    the blank line between
                                    rows.
-------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Here's the caption. It, too, may span\
multiple lines.
```

Renders as:
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to avoid "grid tables" because of this comment in the user-guide: "Note that grid tables are quite awkward to write with a plain text editor (because unlike pipe tables, the column indicators must align)."  Since I am generating this programmatically, I didnt want to have to calculate and pad cell-widths to make sure they line up.  Unless that actually is not necessary.  I note that your example included lined-up pipes.  I was hoping to get away with the simpler Markdown tables.

Comment: Added another section for creating markdown grid tables with tabulate in python.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  This should allow me to use grid-tables without having deal with the column alignment. Thanks!